# top navbar items background does not cover whole space, it covers only the text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple web page and I want the links' background covers the whole space in navbar but it covers only the text around it.

My code is here:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 105%;
  height: 5vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #008083;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="tab">Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Novels</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Films </a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/2snnmcw

Comment: You set a height on the navbar but not on the links, so they are not the same height.

Comment: after removing the height it still shows the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `height` from the `navbar` class so, it'll take the available height. Also, you can add `height` to `.navbar li` (`Optional`, if you want to use some custom height).

```css
.navbar {
  width: 105%;
  /*height: 5vw;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #008083;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
  /*height: 100%;(Optional)*/
}

.navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="tab">Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Novels</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Films </a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you try running this piece of code in the answer? If you want something similar if then what output you are getting?

Comment: when i removed the height even then it showed the same output............i am doing the code on codeplay........ https://www.codeply.com/v/YGLkdTQALE

Comment: Padding was getting applied by <nav>. Here is the updated codeplay https://www.codeply.com/p/EwZyXkFsAD. Added comments.

Comment: thank you so much.......it is working now.......thanks again

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand exact your problem but if your problem with the default margin and padding its a solution

```css
 * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar {
        width: 105%;
        height: 5vw;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        background-color: #008083;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .navbar ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .navbar li {
        float: left;
        /*height: 100%;(Optional)*/
    }

    .navbar li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 1px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .tab {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        background-color: grey;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 1px;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="tab">Biography</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Novels</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Films </a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed some unnecessary style from your code & build this using CSS `display: flex;` instead of `float`. Now `.tab` is covering full `height` with background.

**Here is the working example:**

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #008083;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.tab {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="tab">Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Novels</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Films </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```